# Problem in adjusting website to mobile (Devtools vs real)

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, umijs

I've implemented Media CSS in my website and when I resize it in Chrome-Devtools it adjusts fine.
But when I try it on mobile it shows like in a full desktop page.

Here's my website:
[dinf](https://dinf.net)

when resizing the page in Devtools:
[image: when resizing the page in Devtools]

When simulating mobile
[image: When simulating mobile]

Can you please explain how can that be?

Comment: show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following line to the head tag of your page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It allows elements and fonts to correctly scale on mobile devices. I suggest you to read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) about it.